# Time complexity to convert a decimal to another base

Tags: java, complexity-theory

Here is a code to compute a base version of a decimal number. I am not sure of its time complexity.
Thanks,

```
public static String convertToBase(int num, int base) {
    if (base > 36) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The input argument should be less than or equal to 36.");
    }
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while (num > 0) {
        final int div = num % base;
        if (div > 9) {
            final int sum = div + 55;
            sb.append((char) sum);
        } else {
            sb.append(div);
        }
        num = num / base;
    }
    return sb.reverse().toString();
}
```

Comment: O(n) is the time complexity here

Comment: Is it `num log base` ?

Comment: I agree with New Idiot's Smart answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complexity of the algorithm is

IF Base=36, num=35.............number of iterations is 1
IF Base=02, num=35.............number of iterations is 6

Here number Iterations is = Log of (num) with base of log = base.

Hence time complexity is big-O(Log(n))

Comment: The word is 'algorithm', thanks, not 'algo'. Named after a distinguished mathematician.

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, the answer is `O(1)`.

If `int` was an integer type that supported arbitrary precision, then clearly the answer would be `O(logN)`.

But it is not!  An `int` can get no larger than `Integer.MAX_INT` with is 2^31 - 1 ... or roughly 2 billion.

So, if we let `N` (the unbounded integer) tend to infinity, the value of `num` wraps around so that it never exceeds `Integer.MAX_INT`.  That means that if (for example) `base` is `10`, the `while` loop can execute *at most* `log10(2^31)` times (i.e. 10 times) ... and `convertToBase` is `O(1)`.

However, if you are prepared to abuse the terminology / notation, you *could* say that it is `O(logN)` for small enough `N`.

Comment: I can't really buy this, sorry. The time complexity is O(log(N)) for any value. If N is 1 it is quicker than if N is 32767.

Comment: @EJP - The definition of big-O complexity is in terms of a limit as N tends to infinity.  Here, the value of `num` cannot tend to infinity.  The definition of big-O is not about what is quicker.  It is about how quickly things grow.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you need to define a model of computation before you can answer the question. And you obviously chose a model of computation with finite memory. Which is not helpful at all, since finite memory = finite inputs = finite steps to terminate (if it terminates) = *every* computation terminates in constant time (or doesn't terminate at all). That's why the touring machine has infinite memory and why time complexity is usually based on models with infinite memory.

Answer (score 1):

As Stephen C said, complexity is O(1) since n is bounded.

If n was a arbitrary precision number, complexity would be
O(M(n) log(n))
where M(n) is complexity of multiplication (since there are "num / base" operation).

See
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations#Arithmetic_functions