# Time Complexity Bounded Input

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

According to this question [Time complexity to convert a decimal to another base](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17649524/time-complexity-to-convert-a-decimal-to-another-base)

One of the answer states that

> Strictly speaking, the answer is O(1).
>
> If int was an integer type that supported arbitrary precision, then
>   clearly the answer would be O(logN).
>
> But it is not! An int can get no larger than Integer.MAX_INT with is
>   2^31 - 1 ... or roughly 2 billion.
>
> So, if we let N (the unbounded integer) tend to infinity, the value of
>   num wraps around so that it never exceeds Integer.MAX_INT. That means
>   that if (for example) base is 10, the while loop can execute at most
>   log10(2^31) times (i.e. 10 times) ... and convertToBase is O(1).
>
> However, if you are prepared to abuse the terminology / notation, you
>   could say that it is O(logN) for small enough N.

This led me to think that every algorithm if define as `public myAlgorithm (int i)` is going to be bounded? Let's say I am required to print a String from `0` to `n`.

The code will just be

```
public myAlgorithm (int n) {
  for (int i = 0; i <=n ; i++) System.out.println(i);
}
```

This is clearly O(n) right? But we can just use the "bounded" argument to call it O(1).

Can somebody give me a clearer insight on how I should approach this time complexity?

Answer (score 1):

Because the algorithm is running on the JVM, then the input is bounded. But this is really only a limitation in the implementation, not the algorithm itself. You could theoretically take the algorithm and run it on a variation of Java that has 64-bit integers, or any arbitrary size and it would still be correct.

Because the algorithm doesn't rely on the fact that integers are bounded, then the time-complexity shouldn't either.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it is the quoted answer that is abusing the terminology/notation.  Followed to its logical extreme, EVERYTHING would be O(1), which completely eliminates any utility of determining complexity.

The whole *point* of algorithmic complexity is that it is an abstraction used to help understand the underlying structure of a problem/algorithm.

Comment: Thank you! Now I am at lost to what the actual Time Complexity for base conversion is!

Comment: That would be O(log N).

Answer (score 0):

> This is clearly O(n) right? But we can just use the "bounded" argument to call it O(1).

Bounded result aquisition - well, reference of it - takes O(1), but printing result (string of n characters length) takes O(n) anyway. This logic works when n becomes big enough to measure/notice the difference. For example, printing 2^32 characters will take long enough time to notice it thanks to all the scrolling etc.

Even more, if you feint results for n! computation algorithm that should produce result as correct string representation of real n! value (not modulo 2^64), it will take ages to print characters for, say, 10050050!

Comment: Bounded argument would say that, because n is stored in an int, it is capped by a constant, and thus printing IS O(1).